# Kendo grid custom sort

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a template to display a link in a grid column. The field of that column is bound to a JSON object which has a property 'label' and a property 'link'.

It renders correctly but filtering that column is impossible now because kendo doesn't know how to filter that object. Also sorting doesn't work anymore on that grid because of the same reason.

Is there an easy way to implement custom filter and client side sorting logic for that column?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you set the `field` property to the field you want to use for filtering/sorting, and then use a template to display another column or a formatted result, that should give you what you want.

Depending if you're using MVC helpers or JavaScript or something else I could provide a sample for you.